# How to convert UIColor to SwiftUI‘s Color

Tags: swift, colors, uicolor, swiftui

I want to use a UIColor as foregroundcolor for an object but I don’t know how to convert UIColor to a Color

```
var myColor: UIColor
RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).foregroundColor(UIColor(myColor))
```

Comment: I know I can use the single properties but I thought there might be a simpler method

Comment: I get that but still apple might have provided me with a method already so I thought it would be legit to ask. I'm sorry if you don't think so

Comment: I since found out that there is not a built-in coercion which is why I accepted the answer to help others with the same question.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

Starting with beta 5, you can create a Color from a UIColor:

```swift
Color(UIColor.systemBlue)
```

Comment: I can confirm that this works and if the `UIColor` is a custom dynamic color, the `Color` is also dynamic.

Comment: Worth noting you can just write: `Color(.systemBlue)`

Comment: How would you do it the other way around, Color to UIColor?

Comment: I had to use SwiftUI.Color( myUIColor )

Comment: Seems to work for me to do `UIColor(Color.green)`

Answer (score 59):

## Both iOS and macOS

`Color` has a native initializer for it that takes an `UIColor` or `NSColor` as an argument:

```
Color(.red) /* or any other UIColor/NSColor you need INSIDE parentheses */
```

<sub>**DO NOT** call `Color(UIColor.red)` explicitly **!!!**. This will couple your SwiftUI code to the `UIKit`. Instead, just call `Color(.red)` That will infer the correct module automatically.</sub>

**Also, Note this difference:**

```
Color.red     /* this `red` is SwiftUI native `red` */
Color(.red)   /* this `red` is UIKit `red` */
```

[image: suColor vs uiColor]

#### Note that:

`Color.red` and `UIColor.red` are **NOT** same! They have **different values** and **look different** with each other. So DON'T assume *this worth nothing*

<sub>These are equal instead: `SwiftUI.Color.Red == UIKit.UIColor.systemRed`</sub>

<sub>Also, You can check out **[How to get RGB components from SwiftUI.Color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62994482/5623035)**</sub>

---

### Extension

You can implement a custom variable for it to make it more like `cgColor` and `ciColor`

```
extension UIColor {
    /// The SwiftUI color associated with the receiver.
    var suColor: Color { Color(self) }
}
```

so it would be like:

```
UIColor.red         // UIKit color
UIColor.red.suColor // SwiftUI color
UIColor.red.cgColor // Core graphic color
UIColor.red.ciColor // Core image color
```

---

**Note**: Click [here to see How to **convert `SwiftUI.Color` to `UIColor`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62994667/5623035)

Comment: This is honestly the best answer here. An extension on UIColor to return an `suColor` is brilliant.

Comment: SwiftUI's 'Color.red' is equal to UIKit's 'Color(.systemRed)' or 'UIColor.systemRed' ! This means that SwiftUI implicitly uses systemRed as default for his 'Color.red' , This is nice to know!

Answer (score 9):

Using two helper extensions:

To extract components from `UIColor`:

```
extension UIColor {
    var rgba: (red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat) {
        var red: CGFloat = 0
        var green: CGFloat = 0
        var blue: CGFloat = 0
        var alpha: CGFloat = 0
        getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)

        return (red, green, blue, alpha)
    }
}
```

To `init` with `UIColor`:

```
extension Color {
    init(uiColor: UIColor) {
        self.init(red: Double(uiColor.rgba.red),
                  green: Double(uiColor.rgba.green),
                  blue: Double(uiColor.rgba.blue),
                  opacity: Double(uiColor.rgba.alpha))
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Color(uiColor: .red)
```

Comment: It's important to check the return value of `getRed(_:green:blue:alpha:)`. It can fail.

Answer (score 3):

In Swift UI custom colors with a convenient extension:

```
extension UIColor {
    struct purple {
        static let normal = UIColor(red:0.043, green:0.576 ,blue:0.588 , alpha:1.00)
        static let light = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
        static let dark = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    }
    struct gray {
        static let normal = UIColor(red:0.5, green:0.5 ,blue:0.5 , alpha:1.00)
        static let dark = UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

Wrapping `Color` of `SwiftUI`:

```swift
extension UIColor {
    var toSUIColor: Color {
        Color(self)
    }
}
```

and using this:

```
var body: some View {
    Text("Hello World")
    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.purple.normal))
    .background(Color(UIColor.gray.normal))

    // with wrap
    //.foregroundColor(UIColor.purple.normal.toSUIColor)
    //.background(UIColor.gray.normal.toSUIColor)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a really old hobbyist. Here is one way that works for me.  Yes, I do use globals for reusable statements in a Constant.swift file.  This example is inline so that it is easier to see. I do not say this is the way to go, it is just *my* old way.

### [Screenshot (27k)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngYJ9.png)

```
   import SwiftUI

    // named color from the developer's pallet
    let aluminumColor = Color(UIColor.lightGray)

    // a custom color I use often
    let butterColor = Color.init(red: 0.9993399978, 
                               green: 0.9350042167, 
                               blue: 0.5304131241)

    // how I use this in a SwiftUI VStack:

    Text("Fur People")
           .font(.title)
           .foregroundColor(aluminumColor)
           .shadow(color: butterColor, radius: 4, x: 2, y: 2)
           .minimumScaleFactor(0.75)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an extension like this:

```
extension Color {
    static let someColor = Color(UIColor.systemIndigo) // << Select any UIColor
}
```

**Usage:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
       var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .foregroundColor(.someColor)
    }
}
```