# Setting Row Colors Programmatically in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Currently trying to determine if there is a way to programmatically set colors in SwiftUI.

Here's an example of the code I have that doesn't work.

```
ForEach(listItems, id: \.self) { item in
                                Text(item.name).listRowBackground(Color(item.color))
                            }
```

However manually specifying the color like so does.

```
ForEach(listItems, id: \.self) { item in
                                Text(item.name).listRowBackground(Color.red)
                            }
```

Just wanting to know if anyone else has determined a way dynamically set this with a large selection of colors.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean here by "doesn't work?" Do you receive an error? What is `item.color`? Do you have a self-contained example that demonstrates this issue?

Comment: It does work... debug how you create `Color(item.color)` and if it is really created.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify `item.color` contains a string with the name of a variable, such as `red`, or `blue`.  To add, I don't receive an error, but nothing happens in the UI.

Comment: Realizing that passing it as a string is not correct.  Referenced this post as how to use it properly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57263995/2520506. `item.color` is not set to type UIColor.  variable is set to the following: `UIColor.systemRed`.

Thanks again for the help.