# SwiftUI: Adding effect to control disables interactivity

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How to I apply a `hueRotation`, `blur`, or other effect to a control in SwiftUI and **still allow users to interact with it?**

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State var isOn = true
    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $isOn) {
            Text("The toggle is \(isOn ? "on" : "off")")
        }
            .padding()
            .hueRotation(.degrees(60)) // <-- Disables interactivity
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use  .onTapGesture

Comment: like this link
https://izakpavel.github.io/development/2019/09/30/animating-gradients-swiftui.html

Comment: Using mentioned modifiers you convert control into flat view, just in case. To modify control it should be used either `*style`s, where possible, or `.appearance()` where applicable.

Comment: @jawadAli .onTapGesture + withAnimation gets about halfway there, but that leaves the control with no haptic feedback and no dragging behavior.

Comment: @Asperi, I don't understand your comment. Can you rephrase?

Comment: `Toggle` is a control, but `Toggle.hueRotation()` is not a control in `hue rotation` view, it is just hue rotation view (actually image). You cannot make it back behave like a `Toggle`.

Answer (score 0):

The unfortunate answer is that this appears to be a bug in UIKit backed `View`s (SwiftUI's `Toggle` is actually using `UISwitch` on iOS).  If you modify your code to use something with pure SwiftUI interactivity will work.

```swift
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State var isOn = true
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button("Toggle") {
                self.isOn.toggle()
            }
            Text("Is On: \(self.isOn ? "yes" : "no")")
        }
            .padding()
            .hueRotation(.degrees(60)) // <-- Interactivity still works
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
    }
}
```

You should [file feedback](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/).

Obviously, you would like to style this `Toggle`.  There are some solutions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56479674/set-toggle-color-in-swiftui), though none of them are very satisfying.