# UISwitch.appearance().onTintColor not working since iOS 14

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios14

When recently updating to the latest xcode, all my `UISwitch` changed to use the default color.

Basically it means that this doesn't seem to work anymore:

```swift
UISwitch.appearance().onTintColor = Color.red
```

I can't find a reference to any change and I'm not sure how to get it to work again. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56479674/set-toggle-color-in-swiftui

Comment: @KishanBhatiya Not really, it's even mentioned in the comments that the answer is now invalid since iOS14: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56479674/set-toggle-color-in-swiftui#comment111813416_57562246

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57931945/8697793

Comment: Thanks! It does work, but this is only for iOS 14 and means it'll break on iOS 13. Isn't there something that would work on both?

Comment: You can use `if #available(iOS 14.0, *)`